# Using Method Type in method to deserialize text

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to create a generic Load/Save type of library for my unity game development save slots. Instead of creating implementation each time, I'm trying to create a common one to help out with testing at the very least.

I have this method:

```
public List<T> Load<T>()
{
    string rawSaveData = _dataAccessLayer.Load();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawSaveData))
        List<T> loadedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rawSaveData);
}
```

I am getting probably with the `List<T>` deserialization due to a list needing a strongly typed type.
How do I deserialize the data contained in rawSavaData to type `T`

This is vital that this work because the useage of this method through my projects would be:

```
LevelManager.Load<SaveSlotType>();
LevelManager.Load<DifferentSaveSlot>()
```

No need to worry about how the file is loaded, it is just loaded from a text file to a string then deserialized but that is what is going wrong

Comment: and what is your question exactly?

Comment: How do I deserialize the data contained in rawSavaData to type <T> @AshkanMobayenKhiabani

Comment: @JohneyBronswicAppleton, You deserialized data to type `T` like you did (assuming the data in rawSaveData is the data for a `T` object): `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`. Well, the code line will produce a compiler error. Read it. Then look at the type of your `loadedData` variable to which you want to assign the deserialization result. Then read the error message from the compiler again. Try to understand it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have taken the right path, there are two errors in your code though:

1.You can not declare a variable inside one line if (it is not meaningful as it would be out of scope before you can use it), so declare the `List<T>` outside if

2.Your result is of type `List<T>` not `T` so Deserialize as `List<T>`:

```
List<T> loadedData;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawSaveData))
    loadedData  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(rawSaveData);
```

The whole code would be something like:

```
public List<T> Load<T>()
{
    List<T> loadedData; 
    try{
        string rawSaveData = _dataAccessLayer.Load();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawSaveData))
        loadedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(rawSaveData);
       }
   catch{
      loadedData = new List<T>();
       }
   return loadedData;
}
```